# Simple align-regexp example

Tags: align

I'm trying to align

```
 4000 1 2                 4000  1     2    
  11 1 44          =>     11    1     44   
  1  0000 999             1     0000  999
```

as described at http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AlignCommands

However, typing in `C-u M-x align-regexp`, and accepting all defaults, makes no modifications - my emacs minibuffer is just stuck on `Repeat throughout line? (y or n) y` and I need to press `C-g`. Am I using the command incorrectly or is there something wrong with my emacs (emacs version 22.1.1)

Comment: This is not a solution, but please try to upgrade to the latest stable version (24.5) if you can. Looks like version 22.1.1 is about 7-8 years old! There have been tons of bug fixes and feature enhancements since then.

Comment: Now talking about solution, my emacs is not getting stuck at the final step where you enter `y`. Can you replicate this problem in an `emacs -Q` session? Also, running `C-u M-x align-regexp` with all default values except the last one (`y`) will not give you the result you are looking for. You will need to modify the first value too.. simply append `[0-9]+` to the default regexp.

Comment: Hi. Regarding the version of emacs, unfortunately this is provided to us at work and we don't have root access, but I'll try to see if I can upgrade

Comment: RE: recreating the 'stuck' issue, I can't recreate it now either! Potentially what was happening was with the default parameters, the input wouldn't change post alignment, so it appeared like it was stalling

Comment: RE: the regex used to align the numbers, using your suggestion worked except that a space at the beginning of the row was inserted. Does this mean the suggestion on the linked page is wrong?

Comment: It seems to me that you moved the cursor to some buffer inadvertently from the minibuffer before you hit `y` in that last prompt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29792/discussion-between-taras-and-kaushalmodi).